# How do I remove price suffix (,-) from prices without decimals in WooCommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have a question, and it's my first time ever on a forum. So I'll do my best! :-)

I run a WooCommerce store, but I have a little issue that is affecting the design - or the way the prices are shown on products.

I live in the Netherlands, and it is very common to have the price suffix ',-' here after the amount. However, I've done some research a short while ago, and I managed to find the code that allows me to add that as a price suffix.

But, here's the problem, I don't want to have that price suffix when there are two decimals (e.g. 15,99,-). I only want it to have decimals with rounded prices.

So, at last, clearer examples of what I want:

15,99 (no price suffix)
49,- (price suffix)

I hope you understand my question, and I would be very appreciative if anyone could help me out with this one! Thanks guys!

Comment: So is this PHP or what?

Comment: @emsimpson92 Woocommerce formatting price functions maid with php…

Answer (score 1):

Try using `strpos` to determine if your price contains a decimal first. You'll probably have to convert your number to a string.

```
$price = "52,99";

if(strpos($price, ",") !== true)
{
  $price .= ",-";
}
```

if it doesn't contain a decimal you just append `,-` to the price

Alternatively, you can use `preg_match`

```
if(!preg_match("/,/", $price))
{
  $price .= ",-";
}
```